# Unable to get image data with curl in php

Tags: javascript, php, curl, discord

I am working with Php, I am sending POST Data with curl to "Discord" , data is sending successfully
but i want to get/fetch image(according to user message),In "discord panel" image is showing but in my "curl response"
image/image link is not getting
Here is my code for send data

```
$myChannel = "9999214390985xxxxx";
$myToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$msg = '#Hello';
$data = array('content' => $msg);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/' . $myChannel . '/messages');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string),
    'Authorization: Bot ' . $myToken
    )
);
$answer  = curl_exec($ch);
echo $answer;
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```

And as response i am getting following data

```
{"id": "100101602106435xxxx", "type": 0, "content": "#Hello", "channel_id": "999921xxxxxxx", "author": {"id": "9999083983xxxxxx", "username": "php tutorial bot", "avatar": null, "avatar_decoration": null, "discriminator": "4507", "public_flags": 0, "bot": true}, "attachments": [], "embeds": [], "mentions": [], "mention_roles": [], "pinned": false, "mention_everyone": false, "tts": false, "timestamp": "2022-07-25T06:40:17.400000+00:00", "edited_timestamp": null, "flags": 0, "components": [], "referenced_message": null}
```

Comment: Check if you get any error  if (curl_errno($ch)) {        //check Error
            print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
            exit();
        }

Comment: @AqibJaved : in response i am getting following data

{"id": "1001016021064359997", "type": 0, "content": "#Hello", "channel_id": "999921439098540043", "author": {"id": "999908398327930951", "username": "php tutorial bot", "avatar": null, "avatar_decoration": null, "discriminator": "4507", "public_flags": 0, "bot": true}, "attachments": [], "embeds": [], "mentions": [], "mention_roles": [], "pinned": false, "mention_everyone": false, "tts": false, "timestamp": "2022-07-25T06:40:17.400000+00:00", "edited_timestamp": null, "flags": 0, "components": [], "referenced_message": null}

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object) I notice the following:

`content, embeds, attachments, and components will require a privileged intent in 2022.`

Do you have a privileged intent? And for what property are you expecting an image?

Comment: @Timo: not understand your point,Actually i am using discord first time, i just want for example if someone type "Hello"(dynamic) then he should get "abc.jpg" image (dynamic),

Comment: Okay, but what should that image represent? Is that the profile image of the user? Or an image representing the message? Or another image? I have no experience either with Discord, but it looks like they have a very extension documentation that explains how it works.

Comment: @Timo Right now i saved "dummy image" (any image) and showing statically ( will make dynamically later ), Hope you understand my point

Comment: No, I still don't understand :) When I look at the response you have posted - and the documentation - then I see a number of locations where an image could be. `author` > `avatar`, but that one is `null`, so the author might not have an avatar, and in `attachments`, which is empty. Exactly _what image_ do you want to display?